# In Facebook Graph API - how can I know how many albums a facebook user has?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, pagination

I'm trying to determine if I should show a "next" or "previous" links to the user, in case there are more albums.

When calling `/me/albums?limit=5` for example, for some weird reason the pagination "previous" and "next" links are returned even if there's only one album with a limit of 1000 (trying to exaggerate to prove the point) which is not what happens when I do `/me/friends?limit=5` - in which case I only get a "next" or a "previous" link/data, if there is any.

If I had a way to know how many albums the user has, I could calculate how many "next" the user clicked, and show or not show the "next" or "previous" links.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use FQL to count the number of albums a user has here is the FQL statement that I would use:

```
SELECT aid FROM albums WHERE owner=me();
```

Then just use the length of the array that is returned. Check out the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/album/)

Comment: It is not a solution that uses the Graph API per se, but it's a valid solution.